# How do you tag a build in AWS codebuild

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am migrating our build infrastructure from Jenkins to AWS Codebuild + Codepipeline. In our Jenkins setup we automatically tag the Git project when a build is successful.

How would I do this in AWS Codebuild + Codepipeline?

Answer (score 2):

I understand that it might be not a complete answer, but I have the same question. And I'm going to try the solution which is common for most of CI/CD tools.
Basicaly sometimes during the build (say, on successful build) you need to make a commit to Git repo and push it back to your remote repository. This could be a new tag as well which could be used to kick off deployment or mark a release.
Two methods to access remote Git repository exist: **SSH** and **credentials store**.

As a baseline to enable pushing to Git repository from the build using **credentials store** I'd take a look at this article https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/git-push/

If the solution won't work I'd try with **SSH** https://www.appveyor.com/docs/how-to/private-git-sub-modules/#the-solution